# Why does the BlueROV2 have three clcokwise and three anti-clockwise propellers?

Tags: design

If we look at the Bill of Materials of BlueROV 2 they have written the thrusters separately as clockwise and anticlockwise. Why not use Reverse config. ESC instead of anticlockwise propellers?

Comment: To equalize the torque reaction?

Answer (score 1):

As explained on [their website](https://www.bluerobotics.com/store/thrusters/t200-thruster/):

> The T200 comes with **clockwise and counter-clockwise propellers** to counter torque.

And when you look at the body of the vessel, you can see six thrusters distributed around it.  Given that it's intended for work in confined spaces, I think that it makes sense that you would want the propulsion to be balanced.

[image: base] 
[image: top]

Comment: Glad I got it right with my comment then...